# How to encapsulate a test

Tags: javascript, postman

Given that I have the following Postman test to validate a response's Schema:

```
pm.test("Validate Schema", function () {
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(responseJson.my_key[0]).to.have.keys("key1", "key2", "key3", "key4");
    pm.expect(responseJson.my_key[0].key1).to.have.keys("sub_key1", "sub_key2", "sub_key3");
    pm.expect(responseJson.my_key[0].key1.sub_key1).to.have.keys("sub_sub_key1", "sub_sub_key2", "sub_sub_key3", "sub_sub_key4");
});
```

to validate the example below:

```
    {
         "my_key": [
         {
             "key1": {
                "sub_key_1": "sub_value1",
                "sub_key_2": "sub_value2",
            },
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4"
           }
       ]
   }
```

How do I encapsulate this to reuse the code only changing the name of the keys, that could vary on number.